# A movie in which aliens attack the Earth and destroy it, and then replace it with a new Earth

Tags: identify-this-movie

I have seen a movie when I was 7 or 8, probably released in the late 90s or early 2000s. Here is the plot which I remember:

There is this hero, who is friends with a guy (I don't know the exact details). One day aliens come to the earth and their ship could be seen as a very large one covering the sun from the viewers below. The aliens tell they are going to destroy that planet, and all the humans start worrying... On the day of destruction, the hero's friend uses something (a ring I suppose) to teleport into the alien space ship. A beam of light is released from the ring and then they are in the spaceship.

The friend gives a fish sorta creature to the hero to stuff his ears with, and then they are captured by the aliens inside the ship. The friend tells the hero to tell "It is good" whenever the alien head does something like sing a song or tell a poem. He tells the hero that "those are really worse and that is why I gave you that creature to stuff your ear with". And then when they are with the alien head, he sings a song/ tells a poem to the hero's friend, who considered it unbearable and shouts for help. When the head tells the same poem/song to the hero, the voice appeared distorted and when the alien asks the hero how was it, he tells it was good.

I don't remember the story from now... But in the end, it was a funny and illogical one. As the Earth has been destroyed, a new earth has been created by some guy and they are actually watering the rivers! (Yes sounds weird, but that is how I remember it). Somehow the same humans are there in this new Earth, and the hero asks the guy who created the new Earth to bring all people back alive, and so does he.

I know this plot sounds so bizarre, but that is how I exactly remember it.

Comment: If you think the movie was bizarre, try reading the original book series. Its awesome.

Comment: Haha of course I'd read it.

Comment: @JBCP Technically the radio series predates the book series.

Comment: The best answer would be : 42

Answer (score 56, accepted):

[The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0371724/combined) from 2005.

> Everyone has bad mornings. You wake up late, you stub your toe, you burn the toast...but for a man named Arthur Dent, this goes far beyond a bad day. When he learns that a friend of his is actually an alien with advanced knowledge of Earth's impending destruction, he is transported off the Earth seconds before it is exploded to make way for a new hyperspace motorway. And as if that's not enough, throw in being wanted by the police, Earth II, an insane electronic encyclopedia, no tea whatsoever, a chronically depressed robot and the search for the meaning of life, and you've got the greatest adventure off Earth.

It all happens exactly as you described. Based on [Douglas Adams' cult book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker's_Guide_to_the_Galaxy_%28novel%29). Here's the trailer:

Comment: technically they don't attack and destroy earth it is simply demolished to make space for a hyperspace bypass. If anyone on earth had wanted to protest this they could have during the consultation period.

Comment: @MD-Tech Well, maybe. Without getting into spoilers, let's just say that there may be _ulterior motives_.